# WPF Combobox not showing Selected Value

Tags: wpf, combobox

I know I am the umpteenth with the same problem and I checked a lot of answers on this site, but none of them solved my issue.

I started with a combobox within a datagrid and it works as expected.

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ItemList,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
              DisplayMemberPath="ItemName"                                   
              SelectedValuePath="ItemID"
              SelectedValue="{Binding ItemID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AddRowCheck">
                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=OrderList, Path=CurrentItem}"/>
                </cal:ActionMessage>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

The only problem I have with this one is that when I add `Items` to the `ItemList`, they show up add the bottom of the list and not in alphabetical order anymore.

To solve this, I updated my code like this

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="sortedItemList" 
                              Source="{Binding ItemList}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ItemName" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources> 
    .......
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sortedItemList}}"
              DisplayMemberPath="ItemName"                                   
              SelectedValuePath="ItemID"
              SelectedValue="{Binding ItemID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AddRowCheck">
                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=OrderList, Path=CurrentItem}"/>
                </cal:ActionMessage>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

and now the Items are in alphabetical order, but the selected Item is no longer shown.

What am I a doing wrong?

I tried to override my equal function on my Item object so it checks the ID to see if two items are equal, but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The error was in the event that was triggered after an item is selected.

In the `AddRowCheck` method, I add a new empty row to the datagrid with a ComboBox pointing to the same CollectionViewSource.

I do not understand the logic behind it completely, but after checking this site with this new information I found that I have to set

```
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
```

and it worked.